# Unable to load Windows after using EasyBCD to write MBR

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows 7 Lenovo Ideapad G460 that I'm trying to remove Ubuntu from (decided running Wubi is sufficient for my purposes). I used EasyBCD (The Non-Geeks Guide To Safely Uninstall Ubuntu From A Dual-Booting Machine) to write MBR. Now Windows won't load! I get this error screen.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc0000098

  Info: The Windows Boot Configuration Data file does not contain a valid OS entry.
```

The Operating System Recovery Disc from Lenovo boots to Lenovo Rescue and Recovery 4, or in "Safe mode with command prompt" but immediately crashes. Any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 7 DVD,

- Boot through DVD
- Choose your language
- Repair your computer
- Startup Repair
- Done!